# Getting empty savedStateHandle in jetpack compose when I am using koin

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, koin

I have this view model which is throwing error because `SavedStateHandle` is empty.

```
class DetailViewModel(
    savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle,
    private val repository: Repository
) : ViewModel() {
    private val id: String = savedStateHandle.get<String>("id") ?: error("id must be available")
}
```

I have declared this viewmodel in koin module like this

```
viewModel { (savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle) -> DetailViewModel(savedStateHandle, get()) }
```

I am injecting viewmodel in DetailScreen like

```
@Composable
fun DetailScreen(
    detailViewModel: DetailViewModel = getStateViewModel(),
    onBack: () -> Unit,
) {
```

And I am navigating to DetailScreen like

```
        composable(
            Screen.Detail.route,
            arguments = listOf(
                navArgument(Screen.Detail.NAV_ARG) {
                    type = NavType.StringType
                }
            )
        ) {
            DetailScreen(
                onBack = actions.goBack
            )
        }
```

Did I miss anything?

Comment: Where are you setting the `id` into `SavedStateHandle`?